# How do I get the underlying address in Excel's Hyperlink without VBA

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

In my spreadsheet, there's a `WorkItemRange` with a column of Work Item IDs and another column of links to an external website, which is a formula that boils down to:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://some-tfs/_workitems/edit/" & A1, "TFS Link")
```

In the same spreadsheet but another worksheet, there's a column with a `VLOOKUP` that wants to get the `HYPERLINK`.

```
=VLOOKUP("SomeWorkItemID",WorkItemsRange,2,FALSE)
```

The `VLOOKUP`, however, only returns `TFS Link` instead of the underlying URL, `"http://some-tfs/workitem/" & A1`.

I need to recreate the hyperlink in my second worksheet, like so:

```
=HYPERLINK(?VLOOKUP(), "Click here to open Work Item")
```

How do I formulate my `VLOOKUP` so that it returns the underlying URL? Admittedly, because the second sheet does have access to the Work Item ID, I could just copy the original `HYPERLINK` formula from `WorkItemRange`, but both Range and formula are supposed to be located in a hidden worksheet that is unavailable to the casual users of the spreadsheet.

Also of note, this worksheet is completely devoid of VBA and I'd like to keep it that way.

EDIT: I'm also requesting solutions without Excel 4.0 Functions, if there are any.

Any info is appreciated. It's my first question in SO and gosh I hope I'm doing this right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the scheme:

[image]

you can add a Name from Formulas->Name Manager with the following formula:

```
RetHYP -> =GET.FORMULA(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$12:$A$14;MATCH(Sheet1!$B$13;Sheet1!$A$12:$A$14)))
```

and in the cell:

```
B14 -> =HYPERLINK(MID(RetHYP;1+FIND("""";RetHYP);FIND(";";RetHYP)-(2+FIND("""";RetHYP)));INDEX(A12:A14;MATCH(Sheet1!$B$13;Sheet1!$A$12:$A$14)))
```

The RetHYP return the formula of HYPERLINK, after in the cell you rebuilt the HYPER...

**Using VBA:**
With this function you have the Hyper:

```
Public Function ExtraxtHYP(AllCell As Range, LinkS As String) As String
    Dim Stri, StriN, StriA, AddrS As String
    Dim xx As Range

    For Each xx In AllCell
        If xx.Value = LinkS Then
            Stri = Mid(xx.Formula, InStr(1, xx.Formula, "&") + 1, InStr(1, xx.Formula, ",") - InStr(1, xx.Formula, "&") - 1)
            StriN = Trim(xx.Parent.Name) & "!" & Trim(Stri)
            StriA = (Mid(xx.Formula, InStr(1, xx.Formula, """"), InStr(1, xx.Formula, ",") - InStr(1, xx.Formula, """")))
            StriA = Left(StriA, InStr(1, StriA, "&")) & StriN
            StriA = Application.Evaluate(StriA)
            ExtraxtHYP = StriA
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

First Arg it's the range in the main sheet, and the second the link you search...
With this value you can built the link (sample: in B10 you have "Libero"):

```
=HYPERLINK(ExtraxtHYP(Sheet1!A12:A14;Sheet2!B10);B10)
```

I repeat the best way it's to use some Hidden column to have the data in clear way...

Comment: I tried your solution, but I got a `#VALUE!` error on `FIND(""""; RetHyp)`. I don't really understand why it would be, though. I'm also going to add that I'd like to leave Excel 4.0 functions out of my Worksheet :) Sorry.

Comment: if you write **=RetHYP** in a cell, you have the formula ? You have updated the cell reference in base of your cells ?

Comment: I have updated the references, but I still don't see it :/ What is the expected result of `RetHyp`? And what is actually being searched in `FIND(""""; RetHyp)`?

Comment: if you write in a cell     =RetHyp    in the cell you find     =HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com";"Google")    The mining of FIND it's to find the point in the string of the char " to cut and take only the portion you want...

Comment: Alright, I managed to get something with `RetHyp`, but it returns `=HYPERLINK(RC[-1],"Friendly name")`, and that's only when I added `0` (exact match) to the `MATCH` function in `RetHyp`. Probably there's something different in our Excel settings?

Comment: I managed to get it to work using `GET.CELL(6)`. However, my `HYPERLINK`'s address is a concatenation of several items, and `GET.CELL` (and presumably also `GET.FORMULA` if it had worked) would not return what I wanted (the resulting link) and instead the actual, actual formula (`"http://some-tfs/_workitems/edit/" & A1`). So I guess this isn't the way to go.

Comment: You are right... I think the only way it's to use VBA, but also in this case it's not so simple, because VBA don't see the HYPERLINK. It's necessary to create a function that find and rebuilt the link. The best way (if you can) it's to use a hidden column where you built the hyperlink and after you use in the first page and in the others...

Comment: I think you're right. Alright, I think I'm going to go with a hidden column. Thanks!